# detecting in pure JS if user has clicked on form elems twice

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect, and fire a function if the user has clicked on any of my elements within '`myFormWrapper`' (my form) a second time.

```
var timesClicked = 0;

document.querySelectorAll('myFormWrapper').addEventListener('click', false);
timesClicked++;

    if (timesClicked>1) {

        function() {
            setInterval( jumpRate, 500);
        });
            function jumpRate(){
            var top = document.getElementById("rate").offsetTop;
            window.scrollTo(0, top);
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: so are you saying you need to track each element contained in `myFormWrapper` and run your function if that element has been clicked twice? Or just if anything inside `myFormWrapper` has been clicked and its the second time something has been clicked?

Comment: Yes; any of the form elements within 'myFormWrapper' if they are clicked a second time...

Comment: then I think you have your answer below.

Comment: Is there a need to delay the scrolling by 500 ms?

Comment: Since `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a nodelist, your `document.querySelectorAll('myFormWrapper').addEventListener` won't work. It needs to be either e.g. `document.querySelectorAll('myFormWrapper')[0].addEventListener` or you need to iterate the element list.

Comment: Furthermore, `querySelectorAll()` use a CSS selector, so assuming your element is not of type `<myFormWrapper>` it should be either `#myFormWrapper` for an id or `.myFormWrapper` for a class

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You are using `querySelectorAll`. That function returns a `NodeList`. To add a listener to all elements in the list, you have to iterate over it. Thus the `forEach`.

The provided argument was not a correct selector. I changed it, assuming you are using the class `myFormWrapper`.

You are not providing a callback function correctly. You are passing `false` instead of a function.

You are also wrapping the timeout in a function. you are not calling.

Also, you want to trigger the scrolling only once. In that case you should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. `setTimeout` calls the callback only once after the given milliseconds passed, `setTimeout` will call the callback repeatedly.

The function `jumpRate` does not have to be a named function, you can pass it anonymously.

Try this:

```
var timesClicked = 0;

document.querySelector('.myFormWrapper').forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function () {
        timesClicked++;

        if (timesClicked > 1) {    
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var top = document.getElementById("rate").offsetTop;
                    window.scrollTo(0, top);
                }, 500);
            } 
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: This reports 'Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function'

Comment: I fixed that error, too. That part of the code was only copied. I assumed you that part was working correctly.

Comment: OP wants to track a second click each of the form elements, not the form as a whole, and your solution won't do that using a global counter.

Comment: This still won't work as you track clicks globally, not per element. A better option would be to add a data attribute (e.g. `data-clicked`) on the clicked element and then check against it instead.

Comment: @LGSon That is how you interpret the question. Reading it together with the provided code, I understand it as a global count.

Comment: Yes, that is how I interpret it. Still, if the form has 3 elements and a user click on the first, fill in some data and then click the second, your solution will detect and fire, as that would be a second click. That will mean that the user will only be able to click and fill in the first element, and then, at any next click, will be pushed to the page's top. For me that sounds really wrong...but then again, since the question doesn't have a [mcve], it is hard to tell.